# Setting the HTTP-Proxy/network settings for a specific Wifi network programatically on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, wifi

I need to change the settings for a specific Wifi network to set the HTTP-Proxy (or alternatively the static network settings) programatically on iOS for some automation tasks. Is this even possible on iOS? I'm totally unaware of this platform at all, so I'm sorry if this is trivial to answer.

If it does matter: I can use a jailbroken device but would prefer a solution which doesn't rely on that. I've read a little bit about UI automation, maybe it's possible to do this through this if it's not possible to do this via a program?